# a way to edit udev rules on Android device?

Tags: android, linux

Does anyone know if it is possible to add udev rules on an Android device?  Not talking about udev rules on my host machine, but about udev rules on the actual Android device.  I could not find a udev folder anywhere on my Droid phone, and if I create an /etc/udev directory with an /etc/udev.conf config file with rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/* ... it does not seem to actually do anything.  It seems to ignore any rules that I create.

Comment: Have you installed udev on your Droid ?

Comment: I believe udev is a kernel component, not something you 'install' like another app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android's flavor of the Linux kernel does not use udev; it appears to have been branched from main before udev was stable. Instead, I believe it uses some script called `MAKEDEV`.

This may not be the case with newer phone kernels, but I cannot speak for them as I don't have experience with them.